# Typed.js code in HTML does not work

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to use typed text on my home page. I've added the html and js code and scripts but it does not work. It just displays 3 of the quotes when it should be displaying one quote at a time typed out. Below is my code, any help will be appreciated.

Index.cshtml

```html
 <div class="container">
                <div class="agile_banner_info">
                    <div class="agile_banner_info1">
                        <h3>Welcome To <span>Business</span></h3>
                        <div id="typed-strings" class="agileits_w3layouts_strings"> @*The following text should have the typing effect*@
                            <p>Global leaders <i>in Business Process</i> and Enterprise Content Management</p>
                            <p>Business <i>efficiency</i> through BPM</p>
                            <p>Increasing <i>productivity.</i> Take informed decisions</p>
                        </div>
                        <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner_agile_para">
                        <p>Our aim is to help our customers succeed</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper-inner-tab-backgrounds">
                        <div class="wrapper-inner-tab-backgrounds-first"><a href="single.html"><div class="sim-button button17">Read More</div></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
<script src="~/Content/MyTemplate/js/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#typed").typed({
               
                stringsElement: $('#typed-strings'),
                typeSpeed: 30,
                backDelay: 500,
                loop: false,
                contentType: 'html', 
                loopCount: false,
                callback: function () { foo(); },
                resetCallback: function () { newTyped(); }
            });

            $(".reset").click(function () {
                $("#typed").typed('reset');
            });

        });

        function newTyped() { /* A new typed object */ }

        function foo() { console.log("Callback"); }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added your text in the script and comment out the HTML content. Hope this will help you.

```js
$(function(){
      $("#typed").typed({
        strings: ["Global leaders <i>in Business Process</i> and Enterprise Content Management", "Business <i>efficiency</i> through BPM","Increasing <i>productivity.</i> Take informed decisions"],
        typeSpeed: 110, // typing speed
        backDelay: 500, // pause before backspacing
        loop: true,
      });
  });
```

```html
 <div class="container">
                <div class="agile_banner_info">
                    <div class="agile_banner_info1">
                        <h3>Welcome To <span>Business</span></h3>
                    <!-- <div id="typed-strings" class="agileits_w3layouts_strings"> @*The following text should have the typing effect*@
                            <p>Global leaders <i>in Business Process</i> and Enterprise Content Management</p>
                            <p>Business <i>efficiency</i> through BPM</p>
                            <p>Increasing <i>productivity.</i> Take informed decisions</p>
                        </div>
 -->
                        <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner_agile_para">
                        <p>Our aim is to help our customers succeed</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper-inner-tab-backgrounds">
                        <div class="wrapper-inner-tab-backgrounds-first"><a href="single.html"><div class="sim-button button17">Read More</div></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion. It still does not work. No text at all appears in this case

Comment: @JanineAlexander, Check your jquery and typed script. Have you added that before the close body tag?

Comment: Yes I've checked, Its enclosed inside the body :(

Comment: Can you create the jsfiddle? because it's hard to understand. In my snippet, it's working.